# Erro na leitura, strings e inteiros

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct tetris{
        char nome[16];
        int pontuacao;
};

int main(){
    int i, nteste = 1, J, k, total = 0, maior, menor, pontos;
    while (scanf("%d\n", &J) && J != 0){
        struct tetris jogador[J];
        for (i = 0; i < J; i++){
            fgets(jogador[i].nome, 16, stdin);
            printf("LI NOME");
            total = 0;
            maior = 0;
            for (k = 0; k <= 11; k++){
                if (k == 11)
                    scanf("%d\n", &pontos);
                else
                    scanf("%d", &pontos);
                printf("LI PONTO");
                total += pontos;
                if (pontos > maior)
                    maior = pontos;
                else
                    if (pontos < menor)
                        menor = pontos;
                if (k == 0)
                    menor = maior;

            }
            jogador[i].pontuacao = total - maior - menor;
        }
        printf("ACABEI");
        for (k = 0; k < J; k++){
        printf("%s %d", jogador[k].nome, jogador[k].pontuacao);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Depois que eu digito todos os dados, dessa forma, por exemplo:

```
4
Zezinho
100 123 133 333 400 300 129 200 360 340 200 600
Luizinho
60 50 120 250 170 190 190 220 260 270 290 300
Carlinhos
10 10 20 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20
Joaozinho
200 300 400 400 500 500 500 600 650 650 700 810
```

4 é equivale ao número de jogadores, as *strings* aos respectivos nomes deles e os inteiros às pontuações. Após digitá-los, o meu código (incompleto) deveria imprimir os nomes e as pontuações, mas ao invés disso, ele pede a leitura de mais um valor, que não faço ideia de qual seja.

Já tentei usar `gets`, `scanf`, e agora o `fgets` - cogitando que o erro estivesse na leitura das strings - mas não deu resultado.

O que vem causando isso? Por que no final do caso de testes ele pede mais um valor?

[Link do problema](http://br.spoj.com/problems/OBITETRI/).

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, amigo.
O while executa o programa enquanto o usuário não digitar um J = 0, isto é, quando ele digitar 0, o programa finaliza - é uma exigência do site.
O problema não está na condição de parada das leituras, mas sim na quantidade de leituras que o sistema está pedindo, sempre +1 do que deveria. (Dentro de cada caso de teste, no final)

Comment: Se eu fizer isso, o programa ficará incorreto, pois o site diz "0 <= J <= 1000 (J = 0 apenas para indicar ﬁnal da entrada)"

Comment: Beleza. Só pra tentar elucidar mais o problema: 
Ao invés de digitar isso:
2

Carlos

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

João

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Eu tenho que digitar isso:

2

Carlos

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

João

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 X

Onde X pode ser qualquer coisa, um inteiro ou um caractere.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Este código não faz muito sentido então não dá para saber o que você quer. Ele tem alguns problemas e está mal organizado. Eu fui reestruturando para poder entender e acabei resolvendo o problema. Só não sei se ele faz o que você quer. O principal problema estava no `while`. Até onde entendi ele só existe para garantir que algo acima de zero seja digitado, e não para ficar repetindo tudo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct tetris {
    char nome[16];
    int pontuacao;
};

int main() {
    int j = -1;
    while (scanf("%d", &j) && j != 0) { };
    struct tetris jogador[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        scanf("%15s", jogador[i].nome);
        printf("LI NOME\n");
        int total = 0;
        int maior = 0;
        int menor = 32767; //tem um risco aqui
        for (int k = 0; k <= 11; k++) {
            int pontos = 0;
            scanf("%d", &pontos);
            printf("LI PONTO\n");
            total += pontos;
            if (pontos > maior) maior = pontos;
            else if (pontos < menor) menor = pontos;
            if (k == 0) menor = maior;
        }
        printf("\n");
        jogador[i].pontuacao = total - maior - menor;
    }
    printf("ACABEI\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) printf("%s %d\n", jogador[k].nome, jogador[k].pontuacao);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/yWAZ9f). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xdotgwgp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ReadData.c).

Se quiser uma solução com `while` tem nesse [outro **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KViptM).

Answer (score 1):

Após o scanf você coloque sempre a função `fflush(stdin);` para limpar o buffer do teclado, e dentro do scanf retire os `\n` quem deve imprimir eles deve ser a função `printf("\n")`;

Obs.: se for linux substitua `fflush(stdin);` por `__fpurge(stdin)`;
se for pesquisar existem outras formas de limpar o buffer .

Comment: Eu fiz sem usar isto e a minha está funcionando. Isto não faz sentido e não resolve problema algum.